# Injective morphism of modules induces a surjective morphism on homomorphisms to the fraction field

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

This might be very elementary but I'm not sure I see it. Given an injective morphism of R-modules $f : A \rightarrow B$ is it true that the induced morphims $Hom_R(B, F) \rightarrow Hom_R(A, F)$ is surjective, where F is the fraction field of R?

Is the same thing true if I replace F with R, at least for some rings R?

Comment: F is an injective R-module https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_module#Commutative_examples

Comment: The injective $\Bbb Z$-modules are the divisible abelian groups. $\Bbb Z$ is not divisible.

Comment: Here is a paper about "self-injective rings": http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~zerz/ast10/frobenius1.pdf